# Why does vscode not show the output of my code in the output section?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have already installed the code runner and Python extension for vscode. I also have installed Python 3.7 on my computer. It runs the code, but all it outputs is just this:

[image: img]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the file is saved? There is still a white dot instead of a close `x` on the right of the file tab.

Comment: yep I saved it before running

Comment: turns out i actually didnt save it lol. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The print statement is going to print to terminal, I would change tabs from Output -> Terminal.

I have been using VS Code for Python development for the last month and really have not used OUTPUT.

A tool that I really LOVE is their Jupyter notebook support. With a comment of '#%%' you can create a cell to run that outputs similar to Jupyter notebook. Make sure you download the Python extension from Microsoft.

Example:

```
#%% 
print('hello, world!')
```

Comment: alright, I'll try going to the terminal later. thank you